# JSS Layout Service not returning items from datasource with query

Tags: jss

I am trying to use the JSS service Layout API to get the items from a datasource specified in a control.

When I set a specific item as a datasource, I do get the item fields.

[image]

[image]

But when I use a query to get multiple items, I don't get any data from the service. Only the text of datasource query.

[image]

[image]

I need to get the datasource items in the json. I am missing something?
Should I extend the layout service for this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use Integrated GraphQL to query the rendering data you need: https://jss.sitecore.net/docs/techniques/graphql/integrated-graphql
2. Extend an existing Rendering Contents Resolver or implement a custom Rendering Contents Resolver in order to use a search query as a datasource. The out-of-the-box resolvers are:

   - Datasource Resolver - The default behavior, serializes the rendering's datasource item
   - Datasource Item Children Resolver - Serializes the children of the datasource item
   - Context Item Resolver - Serializes the context item instead of the datasource item
   - Context Item Children Resolver - Serializes the children of the context item
   - Folder Filter Resolver - Serializes the descendents of the datasource item, excluding folders

   You can find information about Rendering Contents Resolvers here, they are fairly straightforward to implement:
   https://jss.sitecore.net/docs/techniques/extending-layout-service/layoutservice-rendering-contents

Comment: I want to be able to change the datasource based on personalization rules. I know it's possible using the layout service. Is it possible with GraphQL?

Comment: Integrated GraphQL is passed a `$datasource` variable that is the parent rendering's datasource - post personalization. So yes, you can use personalization with integrated GraphQL. Connected GraphQL can also be personalized, again using the same `$datasource` variable but from the client side based on the LS response. See [the docs](https://jss.sitecore.net/docs/techniques/graphql/integrated-graphql) for more details.